# NHibernate: "Column 'Reserved Word' does not belong to table ReservedWords." error

Tags: nhibernate

I just upgraded to NHibernate 2.1 from 2.0 and w/o changing my schema now I get the error:

`Column 'Reserved Word' does not belong to table ReservedWords.`

when trying to `.OpenSession()`.

I can add the property:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
```

to the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, which "fixes" the error.

However, it would be helpful to know, why this error is occurring with the upgrade and how I might fix it.

Comment: what DBMS?                       .

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/87811677a167c3c9

Comment: I am getting a similar error. Can you provide additional information on your configuration? Mine is MySQL 5.1, the MySQL->.NET connector 6.1, .NET 3.5 SP1, and NHibernate 2.0. I am also using Fluent-NHibernate 1.0 RTM.

Comment: I've added the property you've said to fix exactly the problem, because I didn't want to mess with a self compiled version of NHibernate

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/auto-quote-tablecolumn-names.html

NHibernate added the ability to automatically quote table and column names that are reserved words for the selected database.

For example if you have a class with a property "Order", if you try to do: SELECT Order FROM MyTable , then most database will fail to parse the query.  In MSSQL, you would have to do SELECT [Order] FROM MyTable to get it to work (hence the quoting of fields).

Generically in NHibernate you can quote fields using `backticks` - ie. in your mapping specifying the column for Order as `Order` would then allow you to use a column called Order.

The change in NHibernate allows the fields that need to be quote to be quoted automatically, so you don't need to add the quotes manually.

Taken from that url, for example mapping:

```
<class name="Order">
   <id type="int">
        <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
   <property name="Select"/>
   <property name="From"/>
   <property name="And"/>
   <property name="Column"/>
   <property name="Name"/>
</class>
```

Would work without having to quote any of the table or column names